# React material ui can not evaluate effect.next

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using React, and the material-ui library for my front-end UI, and on the latest component I implemented, I started getting crashes with an error stating:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'effect.next').
```

It always occurs in a material UI dialog component, I cannot point out anything different from other dialogs I have written in the same project, I also cannot find mentions of this error anywhere. It occurs after 3 or 4 actions on the page/component. Sadly I cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: Which version of MUI you are using?

Comment: I am using 4.12.3

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

If you print so much in the console(errors), then react can desync with itself during the component lifecycle, and crash all of the mounted components. Just close inspect element and it works fine